# Item in GTM Data Layer preview that is not in the Website code

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm having an issue with an item appearing in the Data Layer that the WebDev team swears is not in the code.

What I'm referring to is the contents of Custom Data > Contents - there is an extra item here, the one with the id of 62-1:
[How it looks like in GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjJdp.png)

This item is not present in the site code, as evidenced by this screenshot:
[How it looks like in site code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m2JE.png)

Would anyone happen to know what's going on?

Comment: Can you show any of the tag or trigger details? On your site, are the extra items located anywhere in the site; not just on that specific page? Or are they completely random and arbitrary?